# Convert complex config file to id,parent,key,value format

Tags: perl, parsing, config

I'm trying to convert a config file like the example below so then I can generate SQL commands to insert into my Oracle table. I'm trying to use Perl, but I'm open to try other languages, like Python.

Example of config:

```
# This is a comment
feed_realtime_processor_pool = ( 11, 12 ) ;
dropout_detection_time_start = "17:00";
# Sometimes the config can have sub-structures
named_clients = (
{
  name = "thread1";
  user_threads = (
     { name = "realtime1"; cpu = 11; } # more comments
     { name = "realtime2"; cpu = 12; } # more comments
    );
}
);
```

(...)

Converting (the spaces are just for a better visualization):

```
id,parent, key,                            value
01,null,   'feed_realtime_processor_pool', '11'
02,null,   'feed_realtime_processor_pool', '12'
03,null,   'dropout_detection_time_start', '17:00'
04,null,   'named_clients',                null
05,04,     'name',                         'thread1'
06,04,     'user_threads',                 null
07,06,     'name',                         'realtime1'
08,06,     'cpu',                          '11'
09,06,     'name',                         'realtime2'
10,06,     'cpu',                          '12'
```

So, the questions are:

1. Somebody knows some lib/module that can do this? I could find config parsers, but couldn't find a good one that could give me in a tree format.
2. If not, somebody can give me some suggestion about how should I start this script, maybe using different modules to help me parsing the config? Cleaning and parsing the config is the hardest part for me.

## First Update:

1. I forgot to mention, I have tons of configs to import into my database and this is not a one-time event. This script will be running every time that I have a new config generated by the customers of my company for a different installation.
2. I chose perl because I thought that this could be faster than Python to execute.
3. I'm very familiar with SQL, but I'm not very good at Perl
4. The configs follow the same structure that I put in the example, the only variations are related to number of white spaces between the key/values pairs or the indentation of the curly braces, etc.
5. I already started writing a perl script using DBI, but the main problem is to parse this config into a format that I can easily work with. I'm always finding situations where my regex expressions are breaking and I keep adjusting over and over. If I could just use a lib to parse the config automatically, it would be great. I'm going to try the ones that you guys mentioned.

Thanks!

## Second Update:

Guys, I cross-posted this question on [Perl Monks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1175079) and got another feedback there that I'm testing as well. Will post the answer once I test everything. Thanks.

Comment: Good point, I added more information now. Thanks

Comment: please inform people when you [cross-post](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1175079)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the tips, but I think that the best option is to follow the suggestion that I received from Choroba at the [perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1175079) site. I'm copying here his answer:

"If you can't find a module to parse your config format, write your own parser. Marpa::R2 can help you in the task:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Marpa::R2;

my $input = << '__INPUT__';
# This is a comment
feed_realtime_processor_pool = ( 11, 12 ) ;
dropout_detection_time_start = "17:00";
# Sometimes the config can have sub-structures
named_clients = (
{
  name = "thread1";
  user_threads = (
     { name = "realtime1"; cpu = 11; } # more comments
     { name = "realtime2"; cpu = 12; } # more comments
    );
}
);
__INPUT__

my $dsl = << '__DSL__';

lexeme default = latm => 1
:default ::= action => ::first

Config    ::= Elements
Elements  ::= Element+                              action => grep_def
+ined
Element   ::= (Comment)                             action => empty
            | Name (s eq s) Value                   action => [values]
            | Name (s eq s) Value (semicolon s)     action => [values]
Comment   ::= (hash nonnl nl)                       action => empty
Name      ::= alpha
Value     ::= List
            | String
            | Num
            | Struct
List      ::= (lpar) Nums (rpar s semicolon s)
Nums      ::= Num+  separator => comma              action => listify
Num       ::= (s) digits (s)
            | (s) digits
            | digits (s)
            | digits
String    ::= (qq) nqq (qq semicolon s)             action => quote
Struct    ::= (lpar s) InStructs (rpar semicolon s)
InStructs ::= InStruct+                             action => grep_def
+ined
InStruct  ::= (lcurl s) Elements (rcurl s)
            | (Comment s)                           action => empty
            | Element

s         ~ [\s]*
eq        ~ '='
hash      ~ '#'
nonnl     ~ [^\n]*
nl        ~ [\n]
alpha     ~ [a-z_]+
lpar      ~ '('
rpar      ~ ')'
lcurl     ~ '{'
rcurl     ~ '}'
semicolon ~ ';'
comma     ~ ','
digits    ~ [\d]+
qq        ~ '"'
nqq       ~ [^"]+

__DSL__

sub listify      { shift; [ @_ ] }
sub quote        { qq("$_[1]") }
sub empty        {}
sub grep_defined { shift; [ grep defined, @_ ] }


my $id = 1;
sub show {
    my ($parent, $name, $elems) = @_;
    if (ref $elems->[0]) {
        show($parent, $name, $_) for @$elems;
    } elsif (ref $elems->[1]) {
        if (ref $elems->[1][0]) {
            say join ', ', $id, $parent, $elems->[0], 'null';
            show($id++, $elems->[0], $elems->[1]);
        } else {
            for my $e (@{ $elems->[1] }) {
                say join ', ', $id++, $parent, $elems->[0], $e;
            }
        }
    } else {
        say join ', ', $id++, $parent, @$elems;
    }
}


my $grammar = 'Marpa::R2::Scanless::G'->new({ source => \$dsl });
show('null', q(), ${ $grammar->parse(\$input, 'main') });
[download]
Output:

1, null, feed_realtime_processor_pool, 11
2, null, feed_realtime_processor_pool, 12
3, null, dropout_detection_time_start, "17:00"
4, null, named_clients, null
5, 4, name, "thread1"
6, 4, user_threads, null
7, 6, name, "realtime1"
8, 6, cpu, 11
9, 6, name, "realtime2"
10, 6, cpu, 12
```

Please, note that to install this module, we need to install many dependencies:

```
sudo cpan IPC::Cmd
sudo cpan Module::Build
sudo cpan Time::Piece
sudo cpan Marpa::R2
```

Comment: I appreciate that you post [@Choroba](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)'s answer from perlmonks here. Just for the records: he's also a member of this site. And a great one, if I may say that. :-)

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, yeah, he's really great, agreed.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want Perl to break down a config file and build SQL statements from it, which you can do, but doing it that way also means creating the IDs and that may cause problems if the database auto-increments.

I would recommend learning how to use Perl to interact with the database directly. This area is dominated by two modules: [DBI](https://metacpan.org/release/DBI) and [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/release/DBIx-Class).

Both modules provide methods to create/read/update/delete data and can store the return values from queries so you can use the ids and other table data in subsequent queries. They also have error handling for transactions which is always nice.

If this is a one-off script and you're already familiar with SQL, I'd recommend DBI since it uses a lot of plain SQL and will likely be faster to learn.

If you want an OO solution to using databases in Perl, or if you intend to do a lot of database work, then I'd recommend taking the time to learn DBIx::Class as you can create a full model of the schema for more robust solutions.

In either case, you'll also need the [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle) module which contains the rules DBI and DBIx::Class need to interact with an Oracle database.

**Update:**

I forgot to mention... If you're adamant about converting the config file to SQL statements, you could try [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm) which converts Perl data structures in to SQL statements.

**Update2:**

I'm not sure if there's a module for that specific config syntax, but it looks pretty close to JSON's format, so you could convert the files to that and then load them with the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

The comments will need to be removed, arrays changed from parentheses to square brackets, the equal signs changes to colons, all text will need to be wrapped in quotes, and the semi-colons changed to commas. I think the trickiest part will be to remove the final comma from each block.

Got stuck on removing the trailing commas, but this should get you most of the way there:

```
my $config = <<'CONFIG';
# This is a comment
feed_realtime_processor_pool = ( 11, 12 ) ;
dropout_detection_time_start = "17:00";
# Sometimes the config can have sub-structures
named_clients = (
{
  name = "thread1";
  user_threads = (
     { name = "realtime1"; cpu = 11; } # more comments
     { name = "realtime2"; cpu = 12; } # more comments
    );
}
);
CONFIG

# Remove comments
$config =~ s{[#].+?$}{}mg;

# Convert Arrays
$config =~ s{\(}{[}mg;
$config =~ s{\)}{]}mg;

# Convert key-value seaprators
$config =~ s{=}{:}mg;

# Wrap text in quotes
$config =~ s{"?([\w\d]+)"?}{"$1"}mg;
$config =~ s{"(\d\d?)":"(\d\d?)"}{"$1:$2"}mg; # fix times

# Convert eol delimiters
$config =~ s{;}{,}mg;



# Wrap whole thing in brackets
$config = '{' . $config . '}';

print "$config\n\n";
```

Comment: Interesting... I'll try the SQL::Abstract. But do you know some lib that can just parse the config file into a Perl data structure?

Comment: You could try converting it into JSON syntax and then use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module  to. It looks like all you would need to do is convert the parentheses, equal signs, and semi-colons, and then  wrap all the text in quotes, so something like:

Comment: erm, adding code in a comment didn't work as I expcted. will update my answer with the example

Comment: Yeah, a good path could be to transform in JSON and from there to SQL... I'm also testing this possibility...

Answer (score 1):

Putting Oracle aside, you might be able to do something with your "config" file in Python since its syntax is similar if not compatible (I can't tell you that). But I am not aware of something that would evaluate it in Perl. Instead you could try Config::General which would allow a config file that looks like this:

```
feed_realtime_processor_pool 11
feed_realtime_processor_pool 12
dropout_detection_time_start 17:00
# Sometimes the config can have sub-structures
<named_client thread1>
  <user_threads realtime1>
     cpu 11
  </user_threads>
  <user_threads realtime2>
     cpu 12
  </user_threads>
</named_client>

# etc
```

and then read it:

```
use Config::General;
$config = Config::General->new("my.conf"); 
my %config = $config->getall;
```

Simpler alternatives might be JSON with `use JSON` or XML::Simple, etc. Check them out in CPAN. These will give you tree formats in familiar syntax.

Comment: Thanks albe, will try your suggestions as well. Like I put in the update, my main problem is not the sql, but to parse the config... Thanks.